# how to check whether the value of table are in series with the next value other highlight the cells

Tags: javascript

I have a table which is added by user having to columns from and every time new values are entered by user it should check whether the to value matches the next from values otherwise the cells should be highlighted. it should be pure javacript.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146940/how-to-check-whether-the-value-of-table-are-in-series/61147898?noredirect=1#comment108275422_61147898)

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>From</th>
          <th>To</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>200</td>
          <td>300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>310</td>
          <td>400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>400</td>
          <td>500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>500</td>
          <td>800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>850</td>
          <td>978</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>978</td>
          <td>1000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

function GetCellValues() 
{ 
var table = document.getElementById('mytable'); 
for (var i= 0, i= table.rows.length; i++) 
 { 
    if(table.cell[i]==table.cell[i+1){
     table.cell[i].style.color = red;
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example loop through the rows and then check if the current first cell in the row is not equal to the previous last cell row. Something like:

```js
function GetCellValues() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  let previous = "0";
  for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    if (previous !== table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText) {
      table.rows[i].cells[0].style.color = "red";
    }
    previous = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
  }
}

GetCellValues();
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>310</td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>850</td>
      <td>978</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>978</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```